# Expression type 'SocketIOClientConfigutation' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift

[image]

How to solve this error?

Check the image in description and tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have 2 config variables accessible here, so write `self.config` instead and it will work fine.